# Print multiple strings to a file with the breakline in bat

Tags: string, batch-file

I would like to add to a text file (with absolute path) many strings (one below the other.) I thought I had found the solution using this example:

```
echo hello & echo.world
```

But when I go to run my program, **the program adds only the last string to the text file** (which is # 127.0.0.1 spclient.wg.spotify.com).

Anyone know a solution?

My bat code:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 media-match.com & echo.127.0.0.1 adclick.g.doublecklick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 www.googleadservices.com & echo.127.0.0.1 media-match.com & echo.127.0.0.1 adclick.g.doublecklick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 www.googleadservices.com & echo.127.0.0.1 pagead2.googlesyndication.com & echo.127.0.0.1 googleads.g.doubleclick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 pubads.g.doubleclick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 securepubads.g.doubleclick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 www.omaze.com & echo.127.0.0.1 omaze.com & echo.127.0.0.1 bounceexchange.com & echo.127.0.0.1 core.insightexpressai.com & echo.127.0.0.1 content.bitsontherun.com & echo.127.0.0.1 s0.2mdn.net & echo.127.0.0.1 v.jwpcdn.com & echo.127.0.0.1 d2gi7ultltnc2u.cloudfront.net & echo.127.0.0.1 cs283.wpc.teliasoneracdn.net & echo.127.0.0.1 cs126.wpc.teliasoneracdn.net & echo.127.0.0.1 u.scdn.co & echo.127.0.0.1 cs126.wpc.edgecastcdn.net & echo.127.0.0.1 pagead46.l.doubleclick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 pagead.l.doubleclick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 video-ad-stats.googlesyndication.com & echo.127.0.0.1 pagead-googlehosted.l.google.com & echo.127.0.0.1 partnerad.l.doubleclick.net & echo.127.0.0.1 prod.spotify.map.fastlylb.net & echo.127.0.0.1 adserver.adtechus.com & echo.127.0.0.1 na.gmtdmp.com & echo.127.0.0.1 anycast.pixel.adsafeprotected.com & echo.127.0.0.1 ads.pubmatic.com & echo.127.0.0.1 idsync-ext.rlcdn.com & echo.127.0.0.1 www.googletagservices.com & echo.127.0.0.1 googlehosted.l.googleusercontent.com & echo.127.0.0.1 d361oi6ppvq2ym.cloudfront.net & echo.127.0.0.1 gads.pubmatic.com & echo.127.0.0.1 ads-west-colo.adsymptotic.com & echo.127.0.0.1 geo3.ggpht.com & echo.127.0.0.1 showads33000.pubmatic.com & echo.127.0.0.1 crashdump.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 adeventtracker.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 log.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 analytics.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 ads-fa.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 audio-ec.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 sto3.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 audio2.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 http://audio2.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 www.audio2.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 desktop.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 heads-ec.spotify.com & echo.127.0.0.1 open.spotify.com & echo.#127.0.0.1 spclient.wg.spotify.com >> C:\Users\utente\Documents\bersaglio.txt
```

*I generated the code with a program that I made in c #, this is the code:*

```
    **using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            String n = "\\n", n2;
            String finale = "";

            Console.WriteLine("This little program is used to insert '& echo.'between 2 or more output strings \n \n \nHow many strings do you have?");
            int stringhe = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < stringhe; i++)
            {
                
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("enter string number " + (i + 1));
                n = Console.ReadLine();
                finale = finale +" & echo." + n;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(finale);

            String terminadebug = Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}**
```

Comment: Put parentheses: `(echo hello&echo world) >> "file.ext"`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo.` is useful because use a mark, like an 2 spaces, grammatically good. So, if you want "hello world" in a script, simple:

```
(
echo. The dolphins in the Australia are pretty cool, they eats cups
echo and a lot of fish. They are "fishes"! Haha.
echo I promise that the weed is still there, I don't use that things.
echo end
) >> "file.txt"
```

The "`>>`" is "write in...", if you want to replace all "`>`" is like "write and replace", this replace everything on the text for the thing that you put.

If you want to read the second line of the text file after that, using batch script, I will happy to help you.